# C++ Snake Game Fruit: Change Coordinates or Spawn New Object?

Tags: c++, game-development

I've decided to lean SDL and make a Snake game. I have gotten to coding the spawning of a fruit, which the snake eats to get longer. Every time the snake eats the fruit, the fruit needs to change to a random position on the screen. I can either simply change its coordinates to new random ones, or I can trash the old fruit object (that has been eaten by the snake) and make it point to a new object with new coordinates. Which one is more efficient? Here is some pseudo-code, for reference:

Option 1:

```
if (snake_eats_fruit) fruit->changeCoordinates();
```

Option 2:

```
if (snake_eats_fruit) fruit = new Fruit(); // fruit's constructor sets random coordinates
```

So should I keep the same object and change its coordinates, or make a pointer to a new object with different coordinates? Thanks!

Comment: You always have only one fruit anyway, moving the object seems like the right thing to do. Why bother with creation and deletion, when you do not have to.

Comment: Except that if you want to handle bonuses (i.e. special items that appear randomly during a limited time) you'll have the need to manage multiple "things" ("thing" being the super class of both "fruit" and "bonus"). And in this case, you might want to go with a collection (e.g. list) of things, one of them being the fruit (and you can have multiple fruits - free gameplay twist!). In this context, the `new Fruit()` would make a lot of sense (mind the pitfalls as explained by @manlio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is probably faster. With the second one you have, at least, the additional memory allocation task.

Anyway this is a good example of [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization): performance shouldn't be a concern for this kind of operation.

The snake eats a fruit just occasionally. Between two meals there are a lot of other (complex) events that take place and the action of changing the position of fruit is negligible.

Some aspects you should consider are:

- do I need explicit memory allocation? (`new Fruit()`).

  It can be the source of memory/resource leaks and it can be slower (e.g. [Why should C++ programmers minimize use of 'new'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/3235496)).

  If you really need dynamic allocation use a smart pointer
- with the second option can easily create a [dangling pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17997228/3235496)

  ```
  Fruit *fruit = new Fruit();
  Fruit *fruit2 = fruit;

  // Snake eats fruit.
  delete fruit;
  fruit = new Fruit();

  // now fruit2 points to something which is not valid anymore
  ```

Answer (score 1):

First option is much better for all the reasons manlio stated. 
Additionally, in that case you could also use Observer pattern so that when you call

`fruit->ChangeCoordinates();`

you can increase the score from within that method. Just a thought...

Comment: Oh yeah, I haven't thought about score yet. Thanks!